# Create token to fill form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form to register applicants for jobs, but the users that will fill the form do not have a user to validate that he's a valid user.

The form has a parameter that indicates what job is the applicant looking for.

```
 //This is the controller action
 public ActionResult RegisterApplicant(int job_id)
 {
     var formModel = new FormModel(){
       job_id = job_id
     };
     return View(formModel);
 }

 ///This is the view
@model Jobs.Models.FormModel

 <div class="container">
 @using(Html.BeginForm("RegisterApplicant")){
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.job_id)

   //Other Fields Here
   <input type="submit" value="Save">
 }
 </div>
```

Is there a way to generate a URL plus a token containing the JOB_ID for the job
to call the RegisterApplicant method, to allow a user that is not authenticated to fill
the form.

I want to avoid to explicit show the job_id in the URL that access the method.

I will use that URL to send it by e-mail message to the job seeker.
Thanks.

Comment: You want to send it via URL but not have it show in the URL?  Use encryption?

Comment: Why can't you just put the `Job_Id` into the url and use the normal authentication pathways to pass the user back after login? What is so secret about the `Job_Id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a Guid for each job and associate with job id.

```
var job = new Job()
{
   job_id = <id>,
   token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

JobService.SaveJob(job);
```

Then, change your controller to receive the token and find the job using it.

```
public ActionResult RegisterApplicant(string jobToken)
{
     var job = JobService.GetJobByToken(jobToken);

     var formModel = new FormModel(){
       job_id = job.job_id
     };

     return View(formModel);
}
```

**JobService is just a hypothetical service, because I don't know how is your real code implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that Guid method is a great approach!